# node http requests not executed concurrently if made from same browser

Tags: node.js, http

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        res.write("hello");
        res.end();
    }, 10000);
}).listen(8080);
```

this is my simple node server running on localhost.
Now if i hit this url  localhost:8080  from two different browsers simultaneously, i get response at same time on both browsers i.e after around 10 secs.
But on other hand when i do so from two different tabs of chrome browser, it takes 10 secs for one tab and another 10 secs for 2nd tab.
**Seems like requests are being processed one after another rather than simultaneously.

can somebody explain?**

Comment: Sounds like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a know browser issue, only happens when you make two requests in the same browser (or browser profile) and **separate tabs** (XHR requests can actually be done simultaneously).

Sources:

[Chrome stalls when making multiple requests to same resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513994/chrome-stalls-when-making-multiple-requests-to-same-resource)
[Multiple instances of PHP script won't load concurrently in the same browser from the same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577833/multiple-instances-of-php-script-wont-load-concurrently-in-the-same-browser-fro)